Pagination On Ntive Druid Query
I am applying pagination on native druid query , Currently using limitspec inbuilt function of DruidGroupBy . I am able to set the liimit but there is no option to set offset so that I can get response of a particular page
DruidGroupByQuery.DruidGroupByQueryBuilder builder = getAQIAggregation();
List<OrderByColumnSpec> orderByColumnSpecs = Collections.singletonList(
        new OrderByColumnSpecMap("deviceID", false, null)
);
DefaultLimitSpec limitSpec=new DefaultLimitSpec(pageSize,orderByColumnSpecs);
String dataSource = "test-dataset";
DruidGroupByQuery query = builder
        .dimensions(Collections.singletonList(new SimpleDimension("deviceID")))
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .intervals(Collections.singletonList(interval))
        .filter(inFilter)
        .limitSpec(limitSpec)
        .granularity(aggregationGranularity) // Apply the aggregation granularity
        .build();
// Execute the query using Druid HTTP client





how can I achieve the offset thing in the following code

